# jq in bash script not working from cron job

Tags: bash, macos, cron

I have jq installed and created a bash script that works fine from the terminal shell (executing jq commands to extract info from json file into other files).

But when I schedule this bash script as a cronjab the result of jq renders nothing.
I've tried to pipe the output of the most simple jq --version command to a file, and that stays empty.

What am I missing out?

Comment: The cron job is ran by `root` and `jq` is not available in their PATH variable, which prints an error to stderr, and you only try to redirect stdout, try to following to confirm: `jq >/tmp/my-jq.output 2>&1`. I'm blindly guessing as your question doesn't provide much information.

Comment: it says
jq: command not found

Comment: I found a way round...
changed the cron command to:
bash -l /myscript.sh 

whereas the -l makes the bash shell to load the full environment, equal to the shell environment.

Comment: did you try searching for `bash script not working from cron job` ? 27 answers. Good luck.

Comment: @Yves Or just write the full path to jq? Type `type jq` in your interactive terminal to see where it's located.